# CMS Home Page layout issue

Tags: layout, cms, home, column

When I am adding content to the Home Page via the CMS page named as such, my left column drops down as if it is part of the main content area.  It should stay static on the left.

**Edit**

My page is [southernperformancparts.com](http://southernperformancparts.com) if you want to take a look.  I added some gibberish to show my issue.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the layout of your cms page is 2 columns left and not 1 column (check in the admin).

If it still not shows up properly, then it is a coding issue, so look in page/template/2columns-left.phtml and see how the columns are pulled in there.

Also check the styling of the left column. Other than that you should post some relevant code to inspect.

Comment: That fixed the issue, but it removed my cart block from the right.  Any suggestion on that?

Comment: @Tommy maybe your cart block was included only in the default template, check other templates or you would need to create your custom one.

Comment: Any way you could drop me some code and the file it would need to be placed in to add the cart block back to the right side?  Thank You for you help